# Powershell create share on current server - Grant permission to user/groups

Tags: networking, powershell, permissions, powershell-2.0

I'm having no problem creating a share or assigning permissions, but I'm having a really difficult time actually accessing this fully. I'm the administrator on the server, I'm trying to test prepping the server for other users to access and I'm trying to set the permission, for now, to full access to everyone.

The issue is that when I try to create a new file/folder in the share I get access denied.

Does anyone else encounter this error when making shares through powershell?

Here is the code I have been using:

```
function New-Share 
    {
        param (
        [parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true, Mandatory=$true, HelpMessage="No folder name specified")]
        [string]$FolderName,
        [parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true, Mandatory=$true, HelpMessage="No share name specified")]
        [string]$ShareName,
        [parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true, Mandatory=$false, HelpMessage="No description specified")]
        [string]$Description
        )
    $error.clear()
    # Check for folder; Create it if it doesn't exist
        If (!(Test-Path $FolderName)) 
            {
                New-Item $FolderName -type Directory | Out-Null
            }
            # Check for share; Create it if it doesn't exist
            $Shares=[WMICLASS]"WIN32_Share"
            if (!(Get-WMIObject Win32_share -filter "name='$ShareName'"))
                {
                $Shares.Create($FolderName,$ShareName,0,65535,$Description) | Out-Null
                if (!($error))
                    {
                    # Share created
                    return $true
                    } else {
                    # Error
                    return $false
                    }
                } else {
            # Share Exists
            return $false
            }
    }
```

I've been Invoking the function with this:

```
function bo.Share()
    {
        $domain = [Environment]::UserDomainName
        $BDrive = "$boDrive" + ":\SYNintviewer"
        New-Share -FolderName "$BDrive" -ShareName "SYNintviewer" -Description "SYNintviewer"
    }
```

Comment: So this all works, you just don't have permissions afterwards?  Have you used Set-ACL in the script to try to resolve that, or perhaps even cacls.exe?

Comment: if you comment out the `| Out-Null` from the line `$Shares.Create($FolderName,$ShareName,0,65535,$Description)` what is the ReturnValue?

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I didn't have to set the ACL definitively just need to format it correctly, I think. So far it's working with the new line: 
New-Share -Sharename "SYNintviewer" -Sharepath "$BDrive" -group "Authenticated Users" -auth FULL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually got this working on my own...

Calling this function instead worked:

```
function bo.Share()
{
    $domain = [Environment]::UserDomainName
    $BDrive = "$boDrive" + ":\SYNintviewer"
    echo "$boDrive is BoDRIVE"
    echo "$BDrive is BDRIVE"
    New-Share -Sharename "SYNintviewer" -Sharepath "$BDrive" -group "Authenticated Users" -auth FULL
}
```